# superscript and subscript is not appearing after publishing the project to webserver

Tags: crystal-reports

I am saving a laboratory result name in Oracle database in this format- Sulphate as `SO<sub>4</sub>` (to render as "SO<sub>4</sub>"), subscript is saving in `<sub></sub>` as HTML tag in database and for report I am using SAP Crystal Report with formulas to print the Superscript and Subscript which is printing properly in my development system, but once I published the same to the Web server, it is not.

The subscript font is appearing like 'boxes':
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crystal rendering depends on the printer driver.

Try to assign a default printer on the server (for the user context of the app) that is capable of subscripts.